# messed up my system python

Tags: python, macos, system, dyld

I messed up my osx 10.10 system python. The `Versions` folder now has a non-standard structure, causing issues. Is there any way I can fix this without a factory reset?

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: How did you get there?

Comment: I foolishly followed a blog post telling me to mess with system python... I can't find it anymore....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the system Python (the one built into OSX), that resides in `/System/Library`.

The one in `/Library` is something that you have installed afterwards, using the official [Python distribution](http://python.org) or maybe MacPorts or Homebrew.

To verify that you are running the OS provided python, run

```
which python
```

It should be

```
/usr/bin/python
```

If it is not, check your $PATH variable.

Also check your PYTHONPATH

```
python -c "import sys;print sys.path"
```

Make sure that it does contain `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/...` and no `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/...` entries.

Note that the default site-packages resides in `/Library/Python/...`.

Once you have verified this, you can probably uninstall (or reinstall) the broken Python dist (do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` first to reinstall any third party stuff).

Comment: It looks like my system python is somehow linked to `/Library`

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think you are running the wrong Python, not the system one.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I wound up doing a factory reset, but I will leave this for others who may encounter this problem in the future (myself included)